# React/React Hooks: I'm trying to dynamically change the style of an input with a conditional function that triggers when a user leaves an input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, styling

I have a component I built using React Hooks that features a conditional function for email validation. As it stands now whenever a user leaves the input field, if the field is blank or the format is incorrect an error message will display underneath the input for the type of error respectively. I'm trying to also dynamically change the border color of the input to red to further signal that the field needs attention. I'm pretty new to hooks so I've been tooling around but can't quite figure out how to make this work as is

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Col, Row, Input, Checkbox } from "antd";

function validateEmail(value) {
  const errors = {};
  if (value === "") {
    errors.email = "Email address is required";
  } else if (!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(value)) {
    errors.email = "Email address is invalid";
  }
  return errors;
}

const CustomerDetails = ({ customer }) => {
  const { contact = {} } = customer || {};
  const [disableInput, setDisableInput] = React.useState(false);
  const [errors, setErrors] = React.useState({});
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState(contact.email);

  function onBlur(e) {
    setErrors(validateEmail(e.target.value));
  }

  function clearInput() {
    setInputValue(" ");
  }

  function handleInputChange(event) {
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
  }

  function CheckboxClick() {
    if (!disableInput) {
      clearInput();
    }
    setDisableInput(prevValue => !prevValue);
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col span={8}>
          <StyledInput
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            disabled={disableInput}
            onBlur={onBlur}
          />
          {errors.email && <ErrorDiv>{errors.email}</ErrorDiv>}
        </Col>
        <Col span={8}>
          <Checkbox value={disableInput} onChange={CheckboxClick} /> EMAIL OPT
          OUT
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

const Container = styled.div`
  text-align: left;
`;

const StyledInput = styled(Input)`
  max-width: 100%;
  background: white;

  &&& {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 35px;
  }
`;

const ErrorDiv = styled.div`
  color: #d11314;
`;

export default CustomerDetails;
```

Comment: `<StyledInput style={{ borderColor: errors.email && "red" }} ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not about the hooks, but how to better apply the style conditionally. As [Jonas Wilms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56501042/react-react-hooks-im-trying-to-dynamically-change-the-style-of-an-input-with-a#comment99591287_56501042) already mentioned, the inline styles should fit in this particular case. Otherwise, if you want to have more flexible "styled component" consider using `props` inside the component declaration, in your case it can be:

```
const StyledInput = styled(({ isError, ...rest }) => <Input {...rest} />)`
  max-width: 100%;
  background: white;

  &&& {
    border: 2px solid ${props => props.isError ? 'red' : 'black'};
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 35px;
  }
`;
```

so when you render it - just pass this prop directly as:

```
<StyledInput
  ...
  isError={!!errors.email}
/>
```

Comment: If I wanted to use a specific hex color how could I incorporate that?

Comment: two options: by direct declaration with the "#F0F" (instead of 'red' or whatever), OR you can pass it via props. Something like this: `border: 2px solid ${props => props.isError ? props.errorColor : props.defaultColor};`

Comment: This is working but now I'm getting errors in the console saying ```React does not recognize the `isError` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `iserror` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.``` Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @JCalkins89 hey, no problem! After some researching of this threads (https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/pull/2093) and (https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/135) - check the updated answer, it's probably the only way (as of now) to do this without errors